# Why can't I connect to my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, centos6, ruby

I'm trying to install [tentd-admin](https://github.com/tent/tentd-admin).

The install fails during this step:

```
$ DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/tent_server bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I also tried this:

```
$ DATABASE_URL=postgres://tent:tent@localhost/tent_server bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

The error message I got is:

```
Error: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::Error: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "tent"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sequel-3.43.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:208:in `initialize'
```

My Postgres setup looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.pgpass
localhost:5432:tent_server:tent:tent

postgres=# CREATE USER tent WITH password 'tent';
CREATE ROLE

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE tent_server with OWNER tent;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

`FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "tent"`
Postgres is trying to use `ident` authentication, and it's not working as expected.

### Solution

1. Read the Postgres manual, specifically [the section on `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and [the section on `ident` authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT).
2. Either of the following

   - Realize `ident` authentication is not what you want and configure [something more appropriate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-methods.html).
   - Fix your ident user mapping and/or your `identd` daemon to work as Postgres expects.

### Recommendation

`ident` authentication is pretty lousy (it's client-based security and lying about who you are is trivial for an attacker).
Configure one of the many other authentication methods (with actual security) instead.

Alternatively, connect to a local (unix) socket using `trust` authentication if you prefer (but note that this has security implications of its own).